# Views: Show current user-entered filter

Tags: views

I have a view with an exposed form for searching titles/bodies of content. Is there a way I can display "Showing results for: $keywords" with the values that the user enters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP text filter in core. It is quick and dirty.

Add a Header of global text area to the view. Then add this PHP code using the PHP code text format:

```
<?php
$query_params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if (isset($query_params['title'])) {
  print t("Results for @query", array('@query' => $query_params['title']));
}
?>
```

Exposed filter and sort queries in views are passed as query parameters in the form of:

```
?title=test
```

In the above code I am just looking at the parameter 'title', but you can adapt that code snippet to suit your needs. Just look at your url to see what query parameters are passed along.